# Club two payloads with DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am new to MuleSoft and struggling with a scenario for DataWeave. Can someone please help me with an optimized way to merge two payloads to get the desired output; payload1 has fields and payload2 has Rule Set for those fields;
we need to club every field with their corresponding rules; for example 'name' field needs to be clubbed with 'name' rules, similarly 'roll' field needs to be clubbed with 'roll' rules(their might be multiple rules for single field); and so on:

Data:

payload1 =

```
    [
        {
            "ID" : "1",
            "Name" : "ABC",
            "Roll" : 123,
            "Address" : "PQR-234",
            "Standard" : "5"
        },
        {
            "ID" : "2",
            "Name" : "PQR",
            "Roll" : 456,
            "Address" : "REC-678",
            "Standard" : "7"
        },.
        .
        .
    ]
```

payload2 =

```
    [
        {
            "field" : "Name",
            "field-Type": "String",
            "operator": "Not-In-List" ,
            "condition-Operand-Type": "",
            "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: Name not found in the list."
        },
        {
            "field" : "Name",
            "field-Type": "String",
            "operator": "invalid" ,
            "condition-Operand-Type": "",
            "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: There cannot be special char in a name."
        },
        {
            "field" : "Roll",
            "field-Type": "String",
            "operator": "Not-In-List" ,
            "condition-Operand-Type": "",
            "error-Message": "Roll - Invalid Value: Roll not found in the list."
        },
        {
            "field" : "Address",
            "field-Type": "String",
            "operator": "Not-In-List" ,
            "condition-Operand-Type": "",
            "error-Message": "Address - Invalid Value: Address not found in the list."
        },
        .
        .
        .
    ]
```

Desired Output:

```
    [
        {
            "ID" : "1",
            "Name" : "ABC",
            "data-Quality-Rule" : 
            {
                "field" : "ABC",
                "field-Type": "String",
                "operator": "Not-In-List" ,
                "condition-Operand-Type": "",
                "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: Name not found in the list."
            }
        },
        {
            "ID" : "1",
            "Name" : "ABC",
            "data-Quality-Rule" : 
            {
                "field" : "ABC",
                "field-Type": "String",
                "operator": "invalid" ,
                "condition-Operand-Type": "",
                "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: There cannot be special char in a name."
            }
        },
        {
            "ID" : "1",
            "Roll" : "123",
            "data-Quality-Rule" : 
            {
                "field" : "123",
                "field-Type": "String",
                "operator": "Not-In-List" ,
                "condition-Operand-Type": "",
                "error-Message": "Roll - Invalid Value: Roll not found in the list."
            }
        },
        .
        .
        .
        
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use the keys to filter the list of rules that applies to each element on the payload. I used namesOf() but can be done with pluck() also. Then use the list of rules on each item of the list to map the output, instead of trying to do it on the original payload. And use flatMap() instead of map() to remove the inconvenient nesting of lists on each step.

Script:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun applyRules(p, r)=
    namesOf(p) flatMap ((keyName, order) -> rules filter ($.field == keyName as String))
---
payload flatMap ((item, order) -> 
    applyRules(item, vars.rules) 
    map {
            ID: item.ID, 
            Name: item.Name, 
            "data-quality-rules": $
        }
    )
```

Payload:

```json
[
    {
        "ID" : "1",
        "Name" : "ABC",
        "Roll" : 123,
        "Address" : "PQR-234",
        "Standard" : "5"
    },
    {
        "ID" : "2",
        "Name" : "PQR",
        "Roll" : 456,
        "Address" : "REC-678",
        "Standard" : "7"
    }
]
```

Variable vars.rules:

```json
[
    {
        "field" : "Name",
        "field-Type": "String",
        "operator": "Not-In-List" ,
        "condition-Operand-Type": "",
        "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: Name not found in the list."
    },
    {
        "field" : "Name",
        "field-Type": "String",
        "operator": "invalid" ,
        "condition-Operand-Type": "",
        "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: There cannot be special char in a name."
    },
    {
        "field" : "Roll",
        "field-Type": "String",
        "operator": "Not-In-List" ,
        "condition-Operand-Type": "",
        "error-Message": "Roll - Invalid Value: Roll not found in the list."
    },
    {
        "field" : "Address",
        "field-Type": "String",
        "operator": "Not-In-List" ,
        "condition-Operand-Type": "",
        "error-Message": "Address - Invalid Value: Address not found in the list."
    }
]
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "ABC",
    "data-quality-rules": {
      "field": "Name",
      "field-Type": "String",
      "operator": "Not-In-List",
      "condition-Operand-Type": "",
      "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: Name not found in the list."
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "ABC",
    "data-quality-rules": {
      "field": "Name",
      "field-Type": "String",
      "operator": "invalid",
      "condition-Operand-Type": "",
      "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: There cannot be special char in a name."
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "ABC",
    "data-quality-rules": {
      "field": "Roll",
      "field-Type": "String",
      "operator": "Not-In-List",
      "condition-Operand-Type": "",
      "error-Message": "Roll - Invalid Value: Roll not found in the list."
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "ABC",
    "data-quality-rules": {
      "field": "Address",
      "field-Type": "String",
      "operator": "Not-In-List",
      "condition-Operand-Type": "",
      "error-Message": "Address - Invalid Value: Address not found in the list."
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Name": "PQR",
    "data-quality-rules": {
      "field": "Name",
      "field-Type": "String",
      "operator": "Not-In-List",
      "condition-Operand-Type": "",
      "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: Name not found in the list."
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Name": "PQR",
    "data-quality-rules": {
      "field": "Name",
      "field-Type": "String",
      "operator": "invalid",
      "condition-Operand-Type": "",
      "error-Message": "Name - Invalid Value: There cannot be special char in a name."
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Name": "PQR",
    "data-quality-rules": {
      "field": "Roll",
      "field-Type": "String",
      "operator": "Not-In-List",
      "condition-Operand-Type": "",
      "error-Message": "Roll - Invalid Value: Roll not found in the list."
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Name": "PQR",
    "data-quality-rules": {
      "field": "Address",
      "field-Type": "String",
      "operator": "Not-In-List",
      "condition-Operand-Type": "",
      "error-Message": "Address - Invalid Value: Address not found in the list."
    }
  }
]
```